# Customize view in Jquery Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on an agendaView fullCalendar component

[image]

and I want to make something like

[image]

If you want to go to another day, you have to manually go to it through all days (using 'next' button) and I want to put a day navigator in the space marked in green using the gotoDate function, do you know a way of do it easy or do I have to go to fullCalendar's guts?? The easy way I found is placing a div over the calendar containing the date selector, but I want to know if I can take advantage on the unused space in the calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your element to jQuery HTML structure's pretty easy using the html you want to use using the append, appendTo fucnionts every time the page loads- This avoids ripping fullcalanders guts out and will enable you to upgrade the script without having to rewire everything again.

Then you bind to your customs element click pass data over and call fullCalendars [gotoData](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) method

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, passedYear, passedMonth,passedDay) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', passedYear, passedMonth, passedDay);
}):
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote/accept if you like the answer. Thanks :)